# Swing designer plugin for Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, layout-manager, gui-designer

I am looking for best swing editor  rite now I was looking for eclipse plugin that is [Swing Plugin](https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/wbpro/userinterface/property_pane).  Are there any other plugins for designing Swing apps. that can be installed in Eclipse, and will also generate the code?

Comment: Note that a GUI designer will not really help until you understand how to use and combine the layout managers.  Once most programmers do understand the layouts, they don't like the bloated, obtuse code that 'code generators' churn out.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Well it depends on how good your imagination is or how often you want to run your application to see how it looks. I don't use GUI designers but I can see the reason why some do...

Comment: not so close related to the actual question but: do you know any framework, that will generate form basing on bean annotations?

Answer (score 1):

Not Eclipse, but quite powerful is the swing designer of [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/).

It generates the code you need, and has got a lot of features.